# MS Project how to compare "% Complete" with "Planned % Complete"

Tags: ms-project

I need to have a column to show **Planned % Complete** for a certain date that I will compare with **% Complete** column.

Now **% Complete** formula is

```
cstr(IIf([Duration]=0,0,100*[Actual Duration]/[Duration])) & " %"
```

customize  **Planned % Complete** formula that I make is

```
cstr(IIf([Duration]=0,0,100*ProjDateDiff([Start],[Status Date])/[Duration])) & " %"
```

both formulae give me exactly same result but at task level only. However, the later one does not give correct result at summary level if I use **use formula** for roll-up.

I am really struggling with this, would appreciate your help. Or should I entirely follow different approach.

Comment: To work out the planned % complete surely you need to work that out from a baseline? Looking at current stats will only represent the current position surely?

Answer (score 1):

First, using duration to calculate % complete is unreliable.  Physical percent complete is a better, more precise method.  Second, use earned value.  Cost, schedule, and finish variances inherent in EV methods are already built into MS Project, though a little clugy.  But, you don't have to make up new formulas.